# Root privilege can connect to postgresql db via node, but other cannot

Tags: node.js, postgresql, wiki.js

For setting the wiki.js onto my linux server(ubuntu 20.04), I followed steps with url below.

[wiki.js installation guide](https://www.vultr.com/docs/install-wiki-js-with-node-js-postgresql-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-20-04-lts/)

Following to installation process, starting temporary web with `node server` root can connect to database but other user cannot.

How can I grant the right privilidge to user that named `wikijs` or `nobody` (or else)?

And I attach a picture of the symptoms above.

`node server` with wikijs user.
[image]

`node server` with root user.
[image]

If you need more information, please let me know with comments. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I got a solution for it.

The problem is cannot resolve the "localhost", and it is so beacaue of the `/etc/hosts` has 600 permission.

So, I changed the `/etc/hosts` permission to 644.